# Scope and override of Primary, PrimaryVariant, OnPrimary, Secondary, SecondaryVariant, and OnSecondary colors

Tags: android

When I start a new application in Android Studio with the absolute minimum of pre-configuration ("No Activity"), I still get in `themes.xml` the following:

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_500</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

So there are six colors: `Primary, PrimaryVariant, OnPrimary, Secondary, SecondaryVariant, and OnSecondary`

QUESTION: Where do I find for **each** of those six colors an exhaustive list (of classes, objects, object elements etc.) of for **what** and **when** that color is automatically applied by the `parent theme`?

There is a second theme xml that was also automatically generated, called `themes.xml(night)`.

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Primary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/purple_200</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/purple_700</item>
    <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
    <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_200</item>
    <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/black</item>
    <!-- Status bar color. -->
    <item name="android:statusBarColor" tools:targetApi="l">?attr/colorPrimaryVariant</item>
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
</style>
```

I suppose this what Android choses when the phone works under "Dark Theme".

QUESTION: What do I do when for a **certain object element** (say, the color of the `thumb` of a particular `switch` in a particular `activity`) I want to override the applicable color and set it to my own `myColor`, but in such a way that also under "Dark Theme" the applicable color is overridden by `myColor`?

Deleting the `parent theme` would no doubt give me complete autonomy, but that is apparently not possible.